# Cannot connect to PostgreSQL in Docker through PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, docker

I'm cant connect to PostgreSQL with php code. My Postgresql is docker container.
I get an IP with:

```
docker inspect toshi_db_1
```

How I'm trying to connect:

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=172.17.0.2 port=5432 dbname=toshi_development")or die("Could not connect");
```

> **Error**: Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server:
>   could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
>   Is the server running on host "172.17.0.2" and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I thought there could be problems in PostgreSQL.conf with listen_address configuration parameter, but it allows all connections, so I have no idea where the problem is.

> **UPDATE**: I fixed it myself, just tried to expose wrong port in
>   docker-compose file.

Comment: Did you expose the port correctly when creating the container? Are you using `docker-composer`?

Comment: I'm using docker-composer

Comment: Are you exposing the port 5432 correctly? Show us your 'docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: web: &web
  build: .
  links:
   - db
   - redis
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
  environment:
    TOSHI_ENV: development
  command: bundle exec puma
blockworker:
  <<: *web
  command: bundle exec sidekiq -q blocks -c 1 -r ./config/environment.rb
  ports: []
transactionworker:
  <<: *web
  command: bundle exec sidekiq -q transactions -c 1 -r ./config/environment.rb
  ports: []
peermanager:
  <<: *web
  ports: []
  command: bundle exec ruby bin/peer_manager.rb
db:
  image: "postgres:9.3"
redis:
  image: "redis:2.8"

Comment: I'm trying to run toshi block explorer, but all I need is to connect to postgres database through php code. I cannot ping  that ip from host...

Comment: Are you on a Mac? If so, that IP address is the IP address for the container in the xhyve VM. You can't use that IP from the host machine. You need to forward the port and use `localhost`. OR, ar you trying to access that IP from another container in the same docker-compose file? That should work, but the normal way to do it is with the service name (use `host=tdb` in your PHP code) (Is db the right service name? hard to tell without seeing your docker-compose file with good formatting).

Comment: I'm on windows. I want to reach database in container from the host. Just cant find the solution how can I do it

Comment: @Mindaugas how do you solved this? Could you share? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: I exposed port. in toshi/docker-compose.yml. Edit this part: db:
 image: "postgres:9.3"
 ports:
 - "82:5432"

And in toshi/Dockerfile near EXPOSE 5000 add line EXPOSE 82

Answer (score 7):

I run in the same situation today. The solution was replacing the localhost port with the *name* of the container. Like:

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=toshi_db_1 port=5432 dbname=toshi_development")or die("Could not connect");
```

Not sure if it should be the same with IPs. But doesn't the IPs change?

So, for other people seeing this post: remember that 127.0.0.1 always points to current container. So you must replace that "localhost" part with your container name.